# Windows 8 How to turn off and get to access hard drive

Tags: windows-8

I am using windows 8 for the first time. I found a way to turn off the computer but is seems very convoluted. First, I need to go my account, then I click on the battery sign, then the option to turn off the computer first appears. Before I start this, I need to go the windows start up screen to get my account page.

Can anyone please tell the easiest path to access my hard drive.

Comment: Added an answer about shutting down Win 8. Not sure what this has to do with accessing a hard drive.

Answer (score 2):

To shutdown Windows 8

1. Open the Charms Bar by moving the mouse to the upper left or press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
2. Click `Settings`
3. Click `Power` button

[image: power]